# install python 3 kernel on ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, ipython

I know the question has been asked in the past but couldnt find a satisfying solution.

i want to add a python 3 kernel on ipython
here the "official" instructions seems quite straightforward
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

however i receive the following error:

> C:\Users\Vincent>python3 -m pip install ipykernel 'python3' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

This is on a windows system.

any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific and post the error you get?

Comment: Having had a look at the site you refer to, I'm inclined to say you're following the install instructions for a linux environment rather than Windows? a number of the example commands are preceded by a `$` which is the linux/unix command prompt character?

Comment: Windows can't find your python 3 executable. It has a different name, or it's in a directory that is not on the system $PATH. Here's the official documentation about installing and using python under windows. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: hi yes my python 3 is not on the system path because otherwise i think it will create confusion between python 2 and 3 no? or i will need to rename 1 of the python.exe, which i dont like either?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
windows uses the command py -3 instead of python3 that was suggested in the docs posted above;

Sorry if that was abs obvious for all..